# swift parse app crashes after logout when app resumes

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, crash

My code has a weird bug I'm having trouble solving.

I've built an app using swift and parse. You log in, and are taken to the main page thats a table view. Now at this point if you are logged in, and leave and comeback to the app, everything is fine and dandy.

However, when I log out, the user is then taken back to the log in screen. Now if the user leaves the app, but comes back, the app crashes giving me the error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

It makes no sense to me what could be happening. When the app launches fresh from scratch the user is set to nil, then the user is logged in and everything is cool. When you log out, the user is then set back to nil and taken to the log in screen. If you resume the app, crash.

Is this an issue with how I'm logging out the user?

The relevant code is posted below..

On the login page:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    //checks if there is a matching username with a matching password. if so, lets the user log in.



    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text, password: userPassword.text) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            // Do stuff after successful login.
            //go to main table view
            //get current user
            //display current users locations
            println("login success")


            //shows home screen after successful login.
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showHomeFromLogin", sender: self)
        } else {
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            //display error?
            self.displayAlert("Login Failed", alertMessage: "Double check to make sure the username and password are correct.")
            println("login failed")
        }
    }

}


var activeField: UITextField?





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    username.delegate = self
    userPassword.delegate = self

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //setup so when we tap outside the edit, we close keyboard.
    var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showHomeFromLogin", sender: self)
    }

}
```

On the home page where the user logs out:

```
@IBAction func logoutButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() // this will now be nil
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logoutSegue", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "launchSync", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    //setting table view datasource and delegate.
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self



    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    println(currentUser)

}
```

Breaks in here I think on the line `query.whereKey("User", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)`:

```
func launchSync() {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"ParseLighthouse")
    query.whereKey("User", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) lighthouses.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let light = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in light {
                    println(object.objectId)
                }
            }
            println(objects?.count)
            self.syncToLighthouse(objects!)
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}
```

This launchsync function is called in the view did appear method on my home screen. Is it possible that when the logout segue is performed, the main view controllers is still running in the background so when I resume, that code cant find the user now that its set back to nil?

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  Set an exception breakpoint

Comment: updated my question with where is crashes and maybe an explanation?

Comment: You have to be careful when you use ! - this says "it isn't nil and if it is then crash" it looks like you need to check the optional rather than force unwrapping.

Comment: how would i go about changing that exactly? im fairly new to coding so i could use all the help i can get. thanks!

Comment: what did you save in parse **PFUser** pointer or **the username**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "launchSync", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

you say to call the `launchSync` function whenever the app becomes active.

As mentioned by Paulw11, inside that function you are force unwrapping (using !) on `PFUser.currentUser()` which will return nil when the user is logged out.

You can address this by ensuring that the current user isn't nil

```
func launchSync() {
    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        var query = PFQuery(className:"ParseLighthouse")
        query.whereKey("User", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) lighthouses.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let light = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in light {
                        println(object.objectId)
                    }
                }
                println(objects?.count)
                self.syncToLighthouse(objects!)
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfect. thank you so much. i didnt realize that's what the NSNotificationCenter code was doing, but it makes sense now that you explained that. i updated my code and things are back in action. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If there is the potential for a conditional value to be nil then you need to check the conditional before you use it.  When there is no currently logged in user, `PFUser.currentUser()` will return nil.  When you force unwrap this value with `!` you get an exception.

You can change your code to conditionally unwrap the value -

```
func launchSync() {
    if let currentUser=PFUser.currentUser() {
        var query = PFQuery(className:"ParseLighthouse")
        query.whereKey("User", equalTo:currentUser)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) lighthouses.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let light = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in light {
                        println(object.objectId)
                    }
                }
                println(objects?.count)
                self.syncToLighthouse(objects!)
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ah, you posted this right as I was typing up a response haha